# Processing game user movement

Tags: c#, game, .net

This code is a cycle method. It gets ran every 500 milliseconds to process the movement for users in the game. I've been told that it's been poorly coded and could use some optimizations but they didn't really go into detail. I'm asking if anyone could leave any suggestions on how I can get this method to run more efficiently.

It confuses me a little as I can't see any way to improve it, maybe that's just me though.

```
public void OnCycle()
{
    int userCounter = 0;

    try
    {

        List<RoomUser> ToRemove = new List<RoomUser>();

        foreach (RoomUser User in GetUserList().ToList())
        {
            if (User == null)
                continue;

            if (!isValid(User))
            {
                if (User.GetClient() != null)
                    RemoveUserFromRoom(User.GetClient(), false, false);
                else
                    RemoveRoomUser(User);
            }

            if (User.NeedsAutokick && !ToRemove.Contains(User))
            {
                ToRemove.Add(User);
                continue;
            }

            bool updated = false;
            User.IdleTime++;
            User.HandleSpamTicks();
            if (!User.IsBot && !User.IsAsleep && User.IdleTime >= 600)
            {
                User.IsAsleep = true;
                _room.SendPacket(new SleepComposer(User, true));
            }

            if (User.CarryItemId > 0)
            {
                User.CarryTimer--;
                if (User.CarryTimer <= 0)
                    User.CarryItem(0);
            }

            if (_room.GotFreeze())
                _room.GetFreeze().CycleUser(User);

            bool InvalidStep = false;

            if (User.isRolling)
            {
                if (User.rollerDelay <= 0)
                {
                    UpdateUserStatus(User, false);
                    User.isRolling = false;
                }
                else
                    User.rollerDelay--;
            }

            if (User.SetStep)
            {
                if (_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep2(User, new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.SetX, User.SetY), (User.GoalX == User.SetX && User.GoalY == User.SetY), User.AllowOverride))
                {
                    if (!User.RidingHorse)
                        _room.GetGameMap().UpdateUserMovement(new Point(User.Coordinate.X, User.Coordinate.Y), new Point(User.SetX, User.SetY), User);

                    List<Item> items = _room.GetGameMap().GetCoordinatedItems(new Point(User.X, User.Y));
                    foreach (Item Item in items.ToList())
                    {
                        Item.UserWalksOffFurni(User);
                    }

                    if (!User.IsBot)
                    {
                        User.X = User.SetX;
                        User.Y = User.SetY;
                        User.Z = User.SetZ;
                    }
                    else if (User.IsBot && !User.RidingHorse)
                    {
                        User.X = User.SetX;
                        User.Y = User.SetY;
                        User.Z = User.SetZ;
                    }

                    if (!User.IsBot && User.RidingHorse)
                    {
                        RoomUser Horse = GetRoomUserByVirtualId(User.HorseID);
                        if (Horse != null)
                        {
                            Horse.X = User.SetX;
                            Horse.Y = User.SetY;
                        }
                    }

                    if (User.X == _room.GetGameMap().Model.DoorX && User.Y == _room.GetGameMap().Model.DoorY && !ToRemove.Contains(User) && !User.IsBot)
                    {
                        ToRemove.Add(User);
                        continue;
                    }

                    List<Item> Items = _room.GetGameMap().GetCoordinatedItems(new Point(User.X, User.Y));
                    foreach (Item Item in Items.ToList())
                    {
                        Item.UserWalksOnFurni(User);
                    }

                    UpdateUserStatus(User, true);
                }
                else
                    InvalidStep = true;
                User.SetStep = false;
            }

            if (User.PathRecalcNeeded)
            {
                if (User.Path.Count > 1)
                    User.Path.Clear();

                User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

                if (User.Path.Count > 1)
                {
                    User.PathStep = 1;
                    User.IsWalking = true;
                    User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
                    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
                        User.Path.Clear();
                }
            }

            if (User.IsWalking && !User.Freezed)
            {
                if (InvalidStep || (User.PathStep >= User.Path.Count) || (User.GoalX == User.X && User.GoalY == User.Y)) //No path found, or reached goal (:
                {
                    User.IsWalking = false;
                    User.RemoveStatus("mv");

                    if (User.Statusses.ContainsKey("sign"))
                        User.RemoveStatus("sign");

                    if (User.IsBot && User.BotData.TargetUser > 0)
                    {
                        if (User.CarryItemId > 0)
                        {
                            RoomUser Target = _room.GetRoomUserManager().GetRoomUserByHabbo(User.BotData.TargetUser);

                            if (Target != null && Gamemap.TilesTouching(User.X, User.Y, Target.X, Target.Y))
                            {
                                User.SetRot(Rotation.Calculate(User.X, User.Y, Target.X, Target.Y), false);
                                Target.SetRot(Rotation.Calculate(Target.X, Target.Y, User.X, User.Y), false);
                                Target.CarryItem(User.CarryItemId);
                            }
                        }

                        User.CarryItem(0);
                        User.BotData.TargetUser = 0;
                    }

                    if (User.RidingHorse && User.IsPet == false && !User.IsBot)
                    {
                        RoomUser mascotaVinculada = GetRoomUserByVirtualId(User.HorseID);
                        if (mascotaVinculada != null)
                        {
                            mascotaVinculada.IsWalking = false;
                            mascotaVinculada.RemoveStatus("mv");
                            mascotaVinculada.UpdateNeeded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Vector2D NextStep = User.Path[(User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1];
                    User.PathStep++;

                    if (!_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep(new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(NextStep.X, NextStep.Y), (User.GoalX == User.SetX && User.GoalY == User.SetY), User.AllowOverride))
                    {
                        User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

                        if (User.Path.Count > 1)
                        {
                            User.PathStep = 1;
                            User.IsWalking = true;
                            User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
                            if (User.Path.Count > 1)
                                User.Path.Clear();
                        }

                        NextStep = User.Path[(User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1];
                    }

                    if (User.FastWalking && User.PathStep < User.Path.Count)
                    {
                        int s2 = (User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1;
                        NextStep = User.Path[s2];
                        User.PathStep++;
                    }

                    if (User.SuperFastWalking && User.PathStep < User.Path.Count)
                    {
                        int s2 = (User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1;
                        NextStep = User.Path[s2];
                        User.PathStep++;
                        User.PathStep++;
                    }

                    int nextX = NextStep.X;
                    int nextY = NextStep.Y;
                    User.RemoveStatus("mv");

                    if (_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep2(User, new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(nextX, nextY), (User.GoalX == nextX && User.GoalY == nextY), User.AllowOverride))
                    {
                        double nextZ = _room.GetGameMap().SqAbsoluteHeight(nextX, nextY);

                        if (!User.IsBot)
                        {
                            if (User.isSitting)
                            {
                                User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
                                User.Z += 0.35;
                                User.isSitting = false;
                                User.UpdateNeeded = true;
                            }
                            else if (User.isLying)
                            {
                                User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
                                User.Z += 0.35;
                                User.isLying = false;
                                User.UpdateNeeded = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!User.IsBot)
                        {
                            User.Statusses.Remove("lay");
                            User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
                        }

                        if (!User.IsBot && !User.IsPet && User.GetClient() != null)
                        {
                            if (User.GetClient().GetHabbo().IsTeleporting)
                            {
                                User.GetClient().GetHabbo().IsTeleporting = false;
                                User.GetClient().GetHabbo().TeleporterId = 0;
                            }
                            else if (User.GetClient().GetHabbo().IsHopping)
                            {
                                User.GetClient().GetHabbo().IsHopping = false;
                                User.GetClient().GetHabbo().HopperId = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        if (!User.IsBot && User.RidingHorse && User.IsPet == false)
                        {
                            RoomUser Horse = GetRoomUserByVirtualId(User.HorseID);
                            if (Horse != null)
                                Horse.SetStatus("mv", nextX + "," + nextY + "," + TextHandling.GetString(nextZ));

                            User.SetStatus("mv", +nextX + "," + nextY + "," + TextHandling.GetString(nextZ + 1));

                            User.UpdateNeeded = true;
                            Horse.UpdateNeeded = true;
                        }
                        else
                            User.SetStatus("mv", nextX + "," + nextY + "," + TextHandling.GetString(nextZ));


                        int newRot = Rotation.Calculate(User.X, User.Y, nextX, nextY, User.moonwalkEnabled);

                        User.RotBody = newRot;
                        User.RotHead = newRot;

                        User.SetStep = true;
                        User.SetX = nextX;
                        User.SetY = nextY;
                        User.SetZ = nextZ;
                        UpdateUserEffect(User, User.SetX, User.SetY);

                        updated = true;

                        if (User.RidingHorse && User.IsPet == false && !User.IsBot)
                        {
                            RoomUser Horse = GetRoomUserByVirtualId(User.HorseID);
                            if (Horse != null)
                            {
                                Horse.RotBody = newRot;
                                Horse.RotHead = newRot;

                                Horse.SetStep = true;
                                Horse.SetX = nextX;
                                Horse.SetY = nextY;
                                Horse.SetZ = nextZ;
                            }
                        }

                        _room.GetGameMap().GameMap[User.X, User.Y] = User.SqState; // REstore the old one
                        User.SqState = _room.GetGameMap().GameMap[User.SetX, User.SetY]; //Backup the new one

                        if (_room.RoomBlockingEnabled == 0)
                        {
                            RoomUser Users = _room.GetRoomUserManager().GetUserForSquare(nextX, nextY);
                            if (Users != null)
                                _room.GetGameMap().GameMap[nextX, nextY] = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            _room.GetGameMap().GameMap[nextX, nextY] = 1;
                    }
                }
                if (!User.RidingHorse)
                    User.UpdateNeeded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (User.Statusses.ContainsKey("mv"))
                {
                    User.RemoveStatus("mv");
                    User.UpdateNeeded = true;

                    if (User.RidingHorse)
                    {
                        RoomUser Horse = GetRoomUserByVirtualId(User.HorseID);
                        if (Horse != null)
                        {
                            Horse.RemoveStatus("mv");
                            Horse.UpdateNeeded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (User.RidingHorse)
                User.ApplyEffect(77);

            if (User.IsBot && User.BotAI != null)
                User.BotAI.OnTimerTick();
            else
                userCounter++;

            if (!updated)
            {
                UpdateUserEffect(User, User.X, User.Y);
            }
        }

        foreach (RoomUser toRemove in ToRemove.ToList())
        {
            GameClient client = PlusEnvironment.GetGame().GetClientManager().GetClientByUserId(toRemove.HabboId);
            if (client != null)
            {
                RemoveUserFromRoom(client, true, false);
            }
            else
                RemoveRoomUser(toRemove);
        }

        if (userCount != userCounter)
            UpdateUserCount(userCounter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: 371 lines in one method. Uncle bob would be shedding tears to this :D.

Answer (score 8):

One of the most important things to do while programming is beeing consistent in the coding style.

Using always the same style is important because if you encounter some different style you will pause and wonder what this is about. Having different style makes it hard to grasp as first glance what the code is about.

- Different casing styles for variables names. Sometimes you use `camelCase` and sometimes you use `PascalCase` casing for naming your variables.
- Usage of braces `{}`. Sometimes you use braces for single line `if` statements and sometimes you don't. I would like to encourage you to always use them. Omitting braces may lead to hidden and therfor hard to find bugs.

For naming issues you should take a look at the [.NET Naming Guideline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx).

---

Regarding that **god-method**, you really should break it into smaller methods. Smaller methods are easier to read and understand. Maintaining smaller methods or finding a bug in them is easier as well.

---

You have a lot of duplicated code so I will give you some examples to remove the duplication

```
if (User.PathRecalcNeeded)
{
    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
        User.Path.Clear();

    User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
    {
        User.PathStep = 1;
        User.IsWalking = true;
        User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
    }
    else
    {
        User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
        if (User.Path.Count > 1)
            User.Path.Clear();
    }
}
```

- You don't need to check wether `User.Path.Count > 1` just `Clear()` it. But at taking a closer look at it you can just remove it at all, because you set that property some lines below.
- `PathFinder.FindPath()` seems to be possible to find more than one path, hence you should rename it to **`FindPaths()`**.
- How should it be possible in the `else` part that `User.Path.Count > 1` ever will be `true`?

This can be refactored like so (I left `FindPath` so you may copy&paste)

```
if (User.PathRecalcNeeded)
{
    User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
    {
        User.PathStep = 1;
        User.IsWalking = true;
    }
    User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
}
```

---

Some of the above applies here as well

```
if (!_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep(new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(NextStep.X, NextStep.Y), (User.GoalX == User.SetX && User.GoalY == User.SetY), User.AllowOverride))
{
    User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
    {
        User.PathStep = 1;
        User.IsWalking = true;
        User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
    }
    else
    {
        User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
        if (User.Path.Count > 1)
            User.Path.Clear();
    }

    NextStep = User.Path[(User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1];
}
```

Refactored it will look like so

```
if (!_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep(new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(NextStep.X, NextStep.Y), (User.GoalX == User.SetX && User.GoalY == User.SetY), User.AllowOverride))
{
    User.Path = PathFinder.FindPath(User, _room.GetGameMap().DiagonalEnabled, _room.GetGameMap(), new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(User.GoalX, User.GoalY));

    if (User.Path.Count > 1)
    {
        User.PathStep = 1;
        User.IsWalking = true;
     }
    User.PathRecalcNeeded = false;
    NextStep = User.Path[(User.Path.Count - User.PathStep) - 1];
}
```

---

Only a portion of the really big `if` branch

```
if (_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep2(User, new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(nextX, nextY), (User.GoalX == nextX && User.GoalY == nextY), User.AllowOverride))
{
    double nextZ = _room.GetGameMap().SqAbsoluteHeight(nextX, nextY);

    if (!User.IsBot)
    {
        if (User.isSitting)
        {
            User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
            User.Z += 0.35;
            User.isSitting = false;
            User.UpdateNeeded = true;
        }
        else if (User.isLying)
        {
            User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
            User.Z += 0.35;
            User.isLying = false;
            User.UpdateNeeded = true;
        }
    }
    if (!User.IsBot)
    {
        User.Statusses.Remove("lay");
        User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
    }
```

Why would you remove `"sit"` from the `Statusses` if the user `isLying` ? As you can see there is a lot of duplicated code. The difference between the innner `if..else` is the removing of the `status` and the setting of ``isSitting`vs`isLying`, where the removing of the`status` could be removed because you later remove it anyway.

Refoctored it would look like

```
 if (_room.GetGameMap().IsValidStep2(User, new Vector2D(User.X, User.Y), new Vector2D(nextX, nextY), (User.GoalX == nextX && User.GoalY == nextY), User.AllowOverride))
{
    double nextZ = _room.GetGameMap().SqAbsoluteHeight(nextX, nextY);

    if (!User.IsBot)
    {
        if (User.isSitting)
        {
            User.isSitting = false;
        }
        else if (User.isLying)
        {
            User.isLying = false;
        }
        if (User.isSitting || User.IsLying)
        {
            User.Z += 0.35;
            User.UpdateNeeded = true;
        }
        User.Statusses.Remove("lay");
        User.Statusses.Remove("sit");
    }
```

---

This line makes me wonder as well

if (!User.IsBot && User.RidingHorse && User.IsPet == false)

You should either use the negotiation operator `!` or compare the boolean to `false`. Most say you should use the `!` because it is the idiomatic way. Some say using `== false` is easier to see with bad eyes.

Whatever you use is up to you but as said before, **stick to one style**.

---

Some more wondering is about the overall `User`. In your code a user may be

- a Bot
- a Pet
- a normal user ?
- maybe you should use a base or abstract class user which is inherited by a `Pet` and a `Bot` class ?
- maybe you should break the loop into several methods and process pets, bots and user separately ?

---

Whats the difference between `User.RemoveStatus("mv");` and `User.Statusses.Remove("lay");` yes, at least `"mv"` vs `"lay`" but that is not the point. Again the point is beeing consistent. Either use the method `RemoveStatus()` of the user or use the `Remove()` method of the `Statusses` property.

But while we are at `User.Statusses.Remove("lay");`, what is the user doing ? His the user `lying` or `laying` ? Check its property.

---

There is much more to say but I guess I gave you a start here so you may know what to do yourself.